# StateHasChanged() does not update database values

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Using the code you posted in your new answer. But same error when I add a file and the method `UpdateVergadering` is called.

**vergaderingRepository:**

```
private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _factory;

public VergaderingRepository(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory, IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> factory)
{
    _factory = factory;
}

public async ValueTask<int> UpdateVergadering(Vergadering vergadering)
{
    using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();
    dbContext.Set<Vergadering>().Update(vergadering);
    return await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async ValueTask<Vergadering> GetVergaderingVoorLiveNotulenAsync (int vergaderingId)
{
    using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();
            dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    return await dbContext.Set<Vergadering>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == vergaderingId);
}
```

**The error I get:**

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Bestuurslid' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Comment: Do not keep changing the question, that invalidates the answers. Post a follow-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code never completes the component render, you loop within `OnInitialized`.  You also confuse `OnInitialized` and `OnInitializedAsync`.

Here's a demo page that shows how to use the `System.Timers.Timer` with an event handler hooked up to the timer to handle the data get and UI update.  `OnInitializedAsync` does the initial data get, sets up the timer, wires up the event handler and completes.

```cs
@page "/"
@implements IDisposable
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="alert alert-success">
    @_message
</div>

@code {
    private string? _message = "Not Set";
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Initial data get
        _message = await GetData();

        // set uo the timer and hook up the event handler
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Elapsed += this.OnTimerElapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    // Event handler for the timer
    private async void OnTimerElapsed(object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _message = await GetData();
        // must call this like this as the timer may be running on a different thread
        await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private async ValueTask<string> GetData()
    {
        // emulate an async call to a Db or API
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }

    // Dispose of the event handler when the Renderer has finished with the component
    public void Dispose()
        => _timer.Elapsed -= this.OnTimerElapsed;
}
```

#### Update on DbContexts and Async behaviour

Set up a DbContextFactory:

```cs
    services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(
        options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test"));
```

And then use the factory to get Db context instances as you need them.

```cs
public sealed class MeetingBroker
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> _factory;

    public MeetingBroker(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }


public ValueTask<Vergadering> GetVergaderingByIdAsync(int vergaderingId)
{
    using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();
    // if you aren't editing the data then you don't need tracking.  Imporves performance
    dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

    return await dbContext.Set<TRecord>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == vergaderingId));
}
```

#### DbContextFctory Update

You've implemented the factory, but not the "Unit of Work" pattern.  You're implementation uses the same context for all activity within the repository and will cause usage clashes.

Blazor lives in an async world so you need to code for situations where you have parallel processes running on the same resources.

Your Repository Pattern should look like this:

```cs
private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _factoy;

public VergaderingRepository(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory)
{
    // assigned the factory not a context
    _factory = dbContextFactory;
}

public async ValueTask<Vergadering> GetVergaderingVoorLiveNotulenAsync (int vergaderingId)
{
   // creates a context for each transaction
   using dbContext = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    return await dbContext.Set<Vergadering>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == vergaderingId);
}
```

Comment: @Shaun I updated my question with your response, but it does not work

Comment: Put in a breakpoint on `OnTimerElapsed` and check the `Meeting` object you're getting back from `GetData`.  Also what is `vergaderingBL.GetVergaderingById(VergaderingId)`, an API call or a call into a data pipeline to a DB?  Is it async?

Comment: @Shaun I updated my question above with the code you requested

Comment: @Shaun I put a breakpoint on `OnTimerElapsed` and I got the following error message `System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.'`

Comment: See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Shaun getting an error on the Database call `System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.`

Comment: @Shaun I updated my code in the question

Comment: Have you implemented the DbContextFactory?

Comment: @Shaun Yes, I have. I added it to my question.

Comment: You've implemented the factory, but not the "Unit of Work" pattern.  You're implementation uses the same context for all activity within the repository and will cause usage clashes.  Blazor lives in an async world so you need to code for parallel processes running on the same resources.

Comment: @Shaun I updated my question (Repository code). On the same page where the live update is shown, you can upload a file. So simultaneously an update query is called with EFC. But I get an error message: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Vergadering' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'`

Comment: @Shaun How is this possible? I use NoTracking in the LiveAsync method?

Comment: **LOOK** at your repository code.  Which `DbContext` are both the methods using?  Do not create a class level context  - `_db = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();`.  Copy my `GetVergaderingByIdAsync` exactly.

Comment: @Shaun I updated my question with your code in my repository. Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _factory;

public VergaderingRepository(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory, IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> factory)
  => _factory = factory;

public async ValueTask<Vergadering> GetVergaderingVoorLiveNotulenAsync (int vergaderingId)
{
    using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();
    // Turning off tracking as this is only a query.
    dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    return await dbContext.Set<Vergadering>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == vergaderingId);
}

public async ValueTask<int> UpdateVergadering(Vergadering vergadering)
{
    using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();
    // Tracking is required for updates
    //dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    dbContext.Set<Vergadering>().Update(vergadering);
    return await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Comment: @Shaun nope not working. `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Bestuurslid' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.`

Comment: So what is `Bestuurslid`?

Comment: @Shaun A column in the table `Vergaderingen`. `public ICollection<Bestuurslid> Aanwezigen { get; set; }`

Comment: You have problems in your EF data model which you are going to need to track down.  I'm no expert on EF.